# Datagrid inside FlowPanel is not visible- GWT

Tags: gwt, layout, user-interface, datagrid, flowpanel

I have a Datagrid which I am placing inside a FlowPanel. However, this datagrid is not visible unless I explicitly set its size by doing `datagrid.setSize("100%", "250px")`.

I want the datagrid's width to be 100% but I want its height to change according to the number of rows in it. When is only do `datagrid.setWidth("100%")` the datagrid is still not visible. How do overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGrid` needs to either have an explicit size or be put into a `LayoutPanel` and you must ensure an unbroken chain of `LayoutPanels` up to the `RoutLayoutPanel`.

Here are some possible solutions:

- Use `CellTable` instead of `DataGrid`.
- Calculate the required height (numer of rows * row height) and available size (`getOffsetHeight` on the `FlowPanel`) and manually set the height accordingly.

Comment: I went with using a CellTable. Is there a way to make the header of CellTable static so that only the rows scroll just like in DataGrid. Is there a way to do that with the CellTable?

Comment: Unfortunately the `CellTable` can't do that. That's what the `DataGrid` was made for.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width and height both to 100%. If that stretches things, try setting the height of rows to a specific number (from CSS, preferably), that should create rows of a fixed sized, with potentially empty space under it.